# Difference between too many retries and too many requests errors in GRAPH API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, throttling

I just need an unambiguous detailing about when the following two errors occurs in Graph API:
1. too many retries
2. too many requests

On the below link for Graph API throttling guidance: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling

The reasons which are mentioned for too many requests, under the same circumstances I'm getting too many retries error also.

[image: too many retries error]

What is the difference between the two?